# Not able to centre a Linear Layout and therefore the imageView inside it

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a ImageView dynamically and place it at the center of the center. I tried doing it in xml and I was able. I tried to convert the same thing to code but the imageView always appears at the top left corner of the screen. Can somebody point out what the mistake is ? I'm still new to Android and finding my way. There might be blunders as well.

Thanks

The XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myimg"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/exmp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The code

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Resources res = getResources();
    String pluginPackageName = this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

    int anim = res.getIdentifier("anim_android", "anim",pluginPackageName);
    int transparent_style = res.getIdentifier("TransparentProgressDialog", "style", pluginPackageName);
    int drawable_spinner = res.getIdentifier("exmp", "drawable", pluginPackageName);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((100),( 100));
    imageViewParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

    ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    iv.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    iv.setImageResource(drawable_spinner);

    layout.addView(iv, imageViewParams);
    addContentView(layout, imageViewParams);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);`? That's the only difference I see... (and you still need the correct layout params for `addContentView()`)

Comment: Yup. I tried that as well but I didn't get the second part of your comment. Is the layout params wrong ?

Comment: You are calling `addContentView(layout, imageViewParams)` instead of `addContentView(layout, layoutParams)`

Comment: that didn't make  a difference either.

Comment: It may be that your `LinearLayout` needs `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, because typically your content gets placed in a `FrameLayout` provided by the OS.

Comment: No difference again. I mean, @MBhat posted a code snippet which works on his device but not mine. So kind of confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it exactly as in the XML layout file you have to change `addContentView(layout, imageViewParams);` to `setContentView(layout);`

EDIT:
full code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Resources res = getResources();
    String pluginPackageName = this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

    //int anim = res.getIdentifier("anim_android", "anim",pluginPackageName);
    //int transparent_style = res.getIdentifier("TransparentProgressDialog", "style", pluginPackageName);
    //int drawable_spinner = res.getIdentifier("exmp", "drawable", pluginPackageName);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((100),( 100));
    imageViewParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

    ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    iv.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    layout.addView(iv, imageViewParams);
    setContentView(layout);
}
```

Comment: didn't make a difference either :(

Comment: strange, I just tested on my device and it is working :/
I posted the full code, maybe it will help (change the drawable to the one you have)

Comment: I got an image at the center of the first row sorts. What do I do to get it at the center of the screen ?

Comment: Oddly on my device it  is displayed at the center of the screen, try changing the line `imageViewParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;` to `imageViewParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;`

Comment: Still the same. :( This is so weird. Does it depend on devices ? I mean, it would be insanely tough if the same code starts acting differently on different devices when there is no numeric values involved.

Comment: Can something else be a problem ? This is just a simple android project. I am not using the xml file either. if I was, I should have got an image a the center. There is no other file in the project at all to affect the layout or something like that

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time I got different results on different Android devices :/
What is the SDK version you are targeting?

Comment: I just said yes to API 21 while creating the project . DIdn't think much about it.

Comment: I was targeting 22, but I changed to 21 and didn't see any difference :/
I'm running the tests on a Nexus 5 with Android M and a Nexus 9 with Android 5.1.1.

Try to 'clean' the project and rebuild, sometimes that's all that is needed :)

Comment: Anyway, if you want to that a look at the Android Project that I have, here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3czr2msu5dvq7uu/AndroidTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82429/discussion-between-aadithya-and-mbat).

Answer (score 0):

You have this as the last line in onCreate:

```
addContentView(layout, imageViewParams);
```

Perhaps you meant this?

```
addContentView(layout, layoutParams);
```

Alternatively, maybe this:

```
setContentView(layout, layoutParams);
```

Comment: Changing that made no change. It still appears at the same place. Is there something else that I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Use layoutGravity insted of gravity.

```
imageViewParams.layoutGravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
```

Comment: I don't think there is a parameter like that. Android Studio gave me an error

Answer (score 0):

You've to set the layout_gravity. You can do this way:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

            layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to st Gravity for layoutParams and on the layout again ? Isn't that the same ?